# How do I build a speaker box?

Tags: sound-design, speakers, building

I wanted to build an acoustic box for a woofer and a tweeter, and I wanted to knoe if anyone could guide me on how to make it.
It is worth clarifying that it is translated with Google Translate because I do not speak English well.
any misunderstanding let me know
I attached some pictures with the datasheet of the speakers, and I have a table with the Thiele and Small parameters for the woofer only.
[image: Tweeter datasheet]
[image: Woofer datasheet]
[image: Thiele and Small]

Something to note, is that i didnt made the table, i took it from a website.

I'm looking for some guidance or orientation on where i could get useful information for making the box accordingly. I plan to use the speakers on a daily basis, and for general music consumption, but i would like to take the best performance out of these speakers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best option might be to build them the best you can and then live with them for a year and if you don’t like them take the drivers out and try again.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks for the suggestion, but I would still like to know how to make a box. Whether the box should be big, small, etc. What I'm interested in knowing is how to make a box given the parameters I have.

Comment: https://www.micka.de/en/4kammer2chassis_en.php
https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Calculator/SpeakerBoxEnclosure/
https://pierceaud.io/speaker-box-thiele-small/